# Python string split decimals from end of string

Tags: python, string, ftp, split

I use nlst on a ftp server which returns directories in the form of lists. The format of the returned list is as follows:

[xyz123,abcde345,pqrst678].

I have to separate each element of the list into two parts such that part1 = xyz and part2 = 123 i.e split the string at the beginning of the integer part. Any help on this will be appreciated!

Comment: Note that filenames can contain numbers, so the filename ab1cde with the number 234 will look like ab1cde234, and splitting on the first number will yield ab 1cde234.

Comment: Is the integer part always exactly 3 digits?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|[a-z]+', 'xyz123')
['xyz', '123']
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this using string functions? Thanks for the regex option though!

Comment: Sure, but it will be much slower and more complex.

Comment: @wasimkadak: You are trying to match a pattern, and pattern matching is the purpose of regular expressions. They're not slow, particularly if you compile them (re.compile).

Comment: @Ignacio: I'm concerned that the Q mentions filenames - that regex will fail with anything other than strings of lowercase letters.

Comment: Don't forget to mention the `import statement`. :)

Comment: @Phil: That's a fair concern. But I'm sure the asker knows how to either compensate or to ask for further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

For example, using the re module:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = ['xyz123','ABCDE345','pqRst678']
>>> regex = '(\D+)(\d+)'
>>> for item in a:
...    m = re.match(regex, item)
...    (a, b) = m.groups()
...    print a, b

xyz 123
ABCDE 345
pqRst 678
```

Comment: Thanks guys, from the response the regex option seems a lot better that string functions...I am going to try both of them...thank you for your help!

Comment: +1 for the `\D` and `\d`.  One could also have a faster code with: `regex = re.compile('(\D+)(\d+)').match` and then `(a, b) = regex(item).groups()`.

Comment: @EOL, hi!, just trying to keep it as simple, educational as possible. The OP has only 1 point!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex, then you can do something like this. Note that I have not tested this so there could be a bug or typo somewhere.

```
list = ["xyz123", "abcde345", "pqrst678"]
newlist = []
for item in list:
    for char in range(0, len(item)):
        if item[char].isnumeric():
            newlist.append([item[:char], item[char:]])
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression module [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
import re
def splitEntry(entry):
    firstDecMatch = re.match(r"\d+$", entry)
    alpha, numeric = "",""
    if firstDecMatch:
        pos = firstDecMatch.start(0)
        alpha, numeric = entry[:pos], entry[pos:]
    else # no decimals found at end of string
        alpha = entry
    return (alpha, numeric)
```

Note that the regular expression is `\d+$', which should match all decimals at the end of the string. If the string has decimals in the first part, it will not count those, e.g: xy3zzz134 -> "xy3zzz","134". I opted for that because you say you are expecting filenames, and filenames can include numbers. Of course it's still a problem if the filename ends with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Another non-`re` answer:

```
>>> [''.join(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby('xyz123', lambda x: x.isalpha())]
['xyz', '123']
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't promote this. This lacks readability which is counterintuitive to what Python is about.

Comment: This will also fail if the filename contains numbers, e.g. 'ab1cde234' will return 'ab','1','cde','234'

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.findall(r'(.*?)(\d+$)',x)[0] for x in ['xyz123','ABCDE345','pqRst678']]
[('xyz', '123'), ('ABCDE', '345'), ('pqRst', '678')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its that difficult without `re`

```
>>> s="xyz123"
>>> for n,i in enumerate(s):
...   if i.isdigit(): x=n ; break
...
>>> [ s[:x], s[x:] ]
['xyz', '123']

>>> s="abcde345"
>>> for n,i in enumerate(s):
...   if i.isdigit(): x=n ; break
...
>>> [ s[:x], s[x:] ]
['abcde', '345']
```